# Function works when I'm not logged into Wordpress. However, when I log in then it doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-login

I have a function where I want to add fees based on some calculation. The function works when I am not logged into the site, but does not work when I log in. When logged in, the `Cart` page doesn't show any content (no products or anything else); it just displays a white page with the title 'Cart' and that is all. Here is my code:

```
 function prefix_add_discount_linett(  $cart ) {

     $termID = $_SESSION['clicked'];



// get the quantity total number of the category that have ID '16' and the products options must be "sénior" or "méga". 
    function cat_cart_count( $cat_name, $termID ) {
      $termID = $_SESSION['clicked'];
        $cat_count = 0;        

        foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item) 

            if( (has_term( $cat_name, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id']) && $cart_item['yith_wapo_options'][0]['value']=='sénior') || (has_term( $cat_name, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id']) && $cart_item['yith_wapo_options'][0]['value']=='méga')){
                $cat_count += $cart_item['quantity'];
     }else{
      continue;
     }

// on this one, I have two buttons one is delivery and in this one it is take_away so take away must check if the number is divisible into two or not and I must alawys get an integer number, but when I choose Delivery check if the number is divisible into three or not and I must alawys get an integer number as well.
if($termID=="take_away"){
            if ($cat_count%2 == 1) {     

              $cat_count=$cat_count/2;
              floor($cat_count);           

              }else{

                 $cat_count=$cat_count/2;
                   floor($cat_count);

                    }

 }else{

            if ($cat_count%3 == 0) {        

              $cat_count=$cat_count/3;
              floor($cat_count);

             }else{

                $cat_count=$cat_count/3;
                floor($cat_count);

                  }

       }
                return floor($cat_count);
    }
    cat_cart_count( 16 );


// this function is for getting the minimal price of the category '16' with the options "sénior" or "méga".
    function cat_cart_prix_min( $cat_name ) {

        $testprix = 900000;        

        foreach(WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item)  
         if( (has_term( $cat_name, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id']) && $cart_item['yith_wapo_options'][0]['value']=='sénior') || (has_term( $cat_name, 'product_cat', $cart_item['product_id']) && $cart_item['yith_wapo_options'][0]['value']=='méga')){

                    if ($testprix>$cart_item['yith_wapo_options'][0]['price_original']) {

                        $testprix = $cart_item['yith_wapo_options'][0]['price_original'];

                    }else{

                    continue;

                    }

         }else{

      continue;

        }return $testprix;


    }

     if($termID=="delivery" || $termID=="take_away"){
        $prixmin = cat_cart_prix_min(16);

     $total_QN = cat_cart_count( $cat_name );


// this variable '$simo' it count the total of the quantities multiplied by the minimal price ($simo = quantities * minimal price)
    $simo = $total_QN*$prixmin;

    }

// this one is for counting the fees
      $discount = $simo;
      if($discount>0){
      $cart->add_fee( __( 'Offertes', 'yourtext-domain' ) , -$discount );
    }
    }
    add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'prefix_add_discount_linett' );
```

Comment: `if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;` is aborting your function right?

Comment: I just added it in the last minute I thought it will help me somehow but it doesn't really abort my function.

Comment: yes `if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )return;` stops the execution if you are admin...

Comment: When using `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` hook, `if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;` is mandatory and doesn't have any effect in the execution as it's a front end ajax based script… **First `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees` hook has only one argument: `$cart` but not four**. There is a lot of errors and mistakes in your code and you are embedding an additional function inside your hooked function. You should simplify your code, try to make it clean and commented. Why are you adding inside additional functions and other hooks? you should not.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec the functions 'cat_cart_prix_min()'   and   'cat_cart_min()' are the function that make me able to count the quantity of products of a specific category and it takes the smallest price of specific products so I don't know how to really use them outside the main function "prefix_add_discount_linett()"

Comment: @Simo I am sorry but your actual code is just a real mess. You should better try to explain clearly with words what you are trying to do in a very detailed way in your question itself. For your internal functions, put them outside as they should be. They will work perfectly. Remove hooks from inside as they are not needed for `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`. Try to comment your code.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I just added some comments in the code I hope the code is clear now.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec and about my internal functions, I tried to put them outside but I got an error I think because I haven't given them any action, what action should I give them to make them work?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Okay, I will send you a message there

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I sent you a message there in your contact form.